# Get rid of extra \ in DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I Have a wcf that process an XML and returns back response(as an XML) to the client.
This is the method that return response.

```
 public string ProcessXML(CommonLibrary.Model.TransferData dto, bool Authenticated)
    {

        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ResponseBack));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        utility.utilities utl = new utility.utilities();


        string XMLErrMessage = string.Empty;

        if (Authenticated)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.xml))
            {
                XMLErrMessage = utl.validateXML(dto.xml, xsdFilePath, currentSchema);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(XMLErrMessage))
                {
                    dcs.WriteObject(ms, new ResponseBack() { StatusCode = 101, StatusDescription = "Success" });

                    ms.Position = 0;
                }
                else
                {


                    dcs.WriteObject(ms, new ResponseBack() { StatusCode = 201, StatusDescription = "XML Validation Fails" });
                    ms.Position = 0;
                }


            }

        }
        else
        {


            dcs.WriteObject(ms, new ResponseBack() { StatusCode = 401, StatusDescription = "Authentication Fails" });
            ms.Position = 0;

        }

        string s = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();  // xml result

        return s;
    }
```

I am testing this method and I get 3 xmls taht is returning in s.

XML #1:

```
  <ResponseBack xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CommonLibrary.Model\"             xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><StatusCode>401</StatusCode><StatusDescription>
Authentication Fails</StatusDescription</ResponseBack>
```

XML #2:

```
    <ResponseBack xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CommonLibrary.Model\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><StatusCode>101</StatusCode><StatusDescription>Success</StatusDescription></ResponseBack>
```

XML #3:

```
    <ResponseBack xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CommonLibrary.Model"   xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><StatusCode>201</StatusCode><StatusDescription>XML Validation Fails</StatusDescription></ResponseBack>
```

if you look at XML #1 and #2 there is one extra \ in front of xmls, how I can get rid of that:
  xmlns=\"http://schemas.datac

solution:
I was looking at the result in debug mode in visual studio, so it was showing extra / when I print out the result in text box it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am 100% sure that the `DataContractSerializer` does not produce those backslashes. Either you are looking at your values in Visual Studio's watch, which does escape strings according to the C# syntax, or some other part of your program changes the XML.

Comment: Actually I am looking at value on s in visual studio by putting breakpoints and hovering the mouse over it. But as you see in the XML #3 is does not have that \. As I am looking at all of them same way.

Comment: I think maybe I should make changes to MemoryStream. not familiar with that.

Comment: Please do a Console.WriteLine(s) at the end of your method, that will print the XML without any alterations. If you look at the VS watch, it does put backslashes there, to make it a valid string literal, eg. the string `aa"bb` is shown as the `"aa\"bb"` string literal. But you can use a text or XML visualizer, or copy the raw value, which all work differently.